# Generating PHP warnings

Tags: php, command-line, arguments

How can I generate custom PHP warnings in the same way that warnings for the built-in functions work.

For example:

```
php > fopen(null);
PHP Warning:  fopen() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in php shell code on line 1
php > fopen(null, 'w');
PHP Warning:  fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in php shell code on line 1
php > fopen(array('a'), 'w');
PHP Warning:  fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in php shell code on line 1
```

Let's say I have a function as follows:

```
function my_func($a, $b, $c);
```

What code can I use such that `my_func` will throw similar warnings when called incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for trigger_error. These will show a standard error and are handled by the error_log, display_errors, etc. settings in php.ini

A minimal example is:

```
if (!DoAFunction()) {
  trigger_error("DoAFunction returned false!", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what I am after... doesn't that mean I would have to do this... if (!is_string($a)) { trigger_error("my_func() expects $a to be string", E_USER_ERROR) }

Comment: I guess this works, but I am more interested in how to generate the string "my_func() expects parameter 1 to be a string, array given" in a logical way

Comment: Ahh... it sounds like you want strong typing or something similar. Unfortunately, PHP is very loosely typed, so in general, you have to test types manually. In your case, you'd just put it into your function like you were showing and just have a type test at the beginning. fopen is not a user function, it is coded in C/C++ and probably does something just like the "if (!is_string($param1))" would be in PHP to then throw that warning

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger_error("Here is your herror", E_WARNING);
```